# Express not working with spread operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, express, axios

I'm coding an app where you send by Axios a form, and it posts on a form controlled by Express. But in my app.post(), I have a **...req.body**, which is not showing at the result.

```
  function exibirResultado(id, dados){
            const texto = JSON.stringify(dados)
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = texto
        }

 axios.post('formulario', {
            nome: 'João',
            sobrenome: 'Silva'
        }).then(resp => exibirResultado('post', resp))
```

That's my client code

```
app.post('/formulario', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        ...req.body,
        id: 5
    })
})
```

In the HTML, there is a div with id post but on it, it only appears the form id attribute.

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the express json middleware? if not, express may be having problems parsing the body. try some thing like this:

```
const exp = require("express")
const _server = exp()
_server.use(exp.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

Req.body should be an object, the proof of that is its usage - you can do:

```
const newComment = new Comment({
        body: req.body.body,
        author: req.body.author
    });
```

so if I am not mistaken, you cannot use a spread operator on that, since it's not an array. Just send req.body without the spread operator:

```
app.post('/formulario', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        req.body,
        id: 5
    })
})
```

If you need it to be sent as an array, wrap it in a pair of brackets like this:

```
[req.body]
```

If you were to add it to an existing array, then you could use the spread operator like this:

```
[...req.body]
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the help, it didn't work for me, but I really appreciate that you tried to help me.